# How to format a HTTP response to a HTTP request coming from a getJSON() jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http, http-headers

Here's the thing:

I'm creating a completely custom server for my thesis. At the client side, I want to be able to request a database call which the server processes. It then gives a response in HTTP, providing the query result in JSON.

The way I do the call at the moment: using JQuery's 'getJSON()' method.

dummy example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('./db/q="select * from *"', function(result){
                    process(result);
                });
        });
</script>
```

Running a web page with this script in the browser yields the following HTTP Header at the server side:

```
request: GET /db/q="select * from *"
Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:9000/web/widgets/gauge.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,id;q=0.2
```

My question: how would a HTTP 1.1 response from the server to the browser look like, in order to get the JSON payload from the response in the 'result' parameter in the javascript on the browser?

Comment: First things first, your syntax is wrong. Use a combination of single/double quotes or escape them. Try: 
`$.getJSON('./db/q="select * from *"', function(result){ console.log(result); });` and post what you get in your console.

Comment: What are you using on the server side? PHP?

Comment: ah right, I just made that up on the go, you're right, it's wrong.
Thing is that it doesn't really matter, I did it correct in my own code. the request goes to my server. I just need to know how a HTTP response to the request posted above would look like, generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get JSON data via AJAX with jQuery you don't need to use getJSON. Any `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax` parse automatically JSON if they see it in the response.
2. There's no specific format for the body. As long as it's valid JSON, jQuery will put the root of the JSON object into `result`. For example, if your response is `{foo: 'bar'}`, your `result` object will have the `result.foo` propety set to `"bar"`.
3. In your response, to make jQuery automatically treat the content as JSON, you need to specify the header `Content-Type: application/json`. All the other headers are irrelevant.
4. It may be a better idea to move the query from a GET parameter to a POST one, so you don't have to url-encode it on the query string.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!
While reading your comment I realised there was something else wrong with my logic, thanks for the enlighting moment